# .listview() is not a function error when creating a dynamic listview in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, dynamic-list

I am trying to create a dynamic listview in jquery mobile, after querying the facebook api, to retrieve a user's news feed. Here's part of my mark up:

```
markup += '<li><a href=""><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/picture">'+'<h4>' + name + '</h4><p>' + short_post +'....</p></a></li>';
```

I then have,

```
 $(newsfeedposts).append(markup);

$(newsfeedposts).trigger("create");
```

however after that when i call the

```
$(newsfeedposts).listview("refresh");
```

I get a type error: TypeError: $(...).listview is not a function

my html div tag is this

```
  <div data-role="content"> <div class ="post">
    <ul data-role="listview"  class="ui-listview" id="newsfeedposts" data-divider-theme="b" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="a" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true">
</ul>
  </div>
```

please let me know if you identify what Im doing wrong.This has been taking so longg...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using jQuery-selector the right way. To target an element with an id, use `$('#element_id')` and for an element with a class `$('.element_class')`. So, your selection should be as below.

```
$('#newsfeedposts').append(markup);
```

and then

```
$('#newsfeedposts').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: I had already tried that but it still brings up the same error! is it not recognising the .listview() function? should i include any jquery files? I am currently using the latest version of jquerymobile 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: js libraries are in head? jQuery before jQuery Mobile?

Comment: it works! now :) I had a jQuery script in the html file! one i didnt need. It was this 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

thats y it didnt work!

Comment: thanks and the way u said to have the append and refresh works :)