# Listview looks weird - jQuery

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm having some trouble with my ListView.
It doesn't have the nice look that jQuery offers, but just a plain list and I don't have any idea how this would come.

This is the code (HTML)

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Bestelling</h1>
        <a class="ui-btn-right" href="#toevoegen">+</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="bestellingLijst">
            <!-- Hier komt de bestelling -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the code where I add a new `<li>` to the listview

```
$("#bestellingLijst").append("<li>" + naam + ' - ' + prijs + "</li>");
```

[image]

Can anybody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: have you included css?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.listview() is not a function error when creating a dynamic listview in jquery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323981/listview-is-not-a-function-error-when-creating-a-dynamic-listview-in-jquery-m)

Comment: @karthikr Nop, I don't have any

Comment: You need to include CSS. jQuery only provides the javascript part, Not the CSS. You might want to include the `jquery-ui` css or bootstrap css or something to get the styling

Comment: Well, I have linked "jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" as my stylesheet. Is this enough or do I need more?

Comment: @karthikr jQM also provides a `css` file along with the `js` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Sometimes, its required to use `promise` to make `listview("refresh")` wait till the append is done, then call a success handler which takes runs the `refresh` on the `listview`.

```
$("#bestellingLijst").append("<li>" + naam + ' - ' + prijs + "</li>").promise().done( function(){
    $(this).listview('refresh');
});
```

If you're calling append in a loop, it might be better to store it in a variable first, then append it all into `#bestellingLijst` :

```
var i = 0;
var li = "";
for(; i< array.length; i++)
{
  //concat to string
  li += "<li>" + naam + ' - ' + prijs + "</li>";
}
$("#bestellingLijst").append(li).promise().done( function(){
      $(this).listview('refresh');
});
```

**Demo**

<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/CdQTW/</kbd>

**More info on the methods used**

**`listview("refresh")`**

- Docs : <kbd>http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh</kbd>
- What it does : refreshes the markup of dynamically created `ul`s which have `data-role` set to `listview`.

**`promise`**

- Docs : <kbd>http://api.jquery.com/promise/</kbd>
- What it does : Makes sure that all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have finished.

**`done`**

- Docs : <kbd>http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/</kbd>
- What it does : Add handlers to be called when the promise is resolved.

**Extras**

And, I hope you're calling this refresh in a page event method of jQM like this,if you're running this on load of the page :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#home", function () {
  //append to ul
  //refresh the listview
});
```

Comment: Great, that solved it! Thanks for the interesting info, I really appreciate it. That's why I love Stackoverflow so much :-D

Answer (score 0):

If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the refresh() method on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are added.

```
$('#bestellingLijst').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: That didn't solve anything. The listview still looks the same

Comment: This is a correct answer, you are probably doing it wrong. can you post more of your code?