# Error in jquery ListView

Tags: jquery, html, listview

hi im trying to display dynamically using jquery... it is not working.my html is...

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="two">
```

script file..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var i=0;
while(i<10){
  $('#two').append('<li>'+i+'</li>');
 i++; 
 }

  });
```

all the values are displaying in single

1,2,3,...10

but i want to display it like this

1

2

......

10

and i tried $('#two).listview('refresh');

Comment: What is meant by 'into single unordered list'?

Comment: works fine for me, got 10 li from 0 to 9

Comment: try adding a close tag to your ul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing your while loop to a for loop - not sure that would make much of a difference though:

```
$(function(){ // shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        $('#two').append('<li>'+i+'</li>');
    }
});
```

Are you closing your `<ul>` with `</ul>` after running the loop?

Your `<li>` elements could possibly be set to `display: inline` in your css as well.

EDIT - If none of the above works, you could try the jQuery `.promise()` function as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17409282/3112083).