# dynamic listview not being styled by jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm bringing external data via JSON for my app. The loading of data is OK.
The problem is when I display this data. I have this page:

```
<!-- cinema -->
<div data-role="page" id="cinema">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>WGBN Cinema Salvador</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d" id="programa">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this javascript to this page:

```
$(document).delegate("#cinema", "pageinit", function(data) {
        // loop nas salas
        $.each($.objCinema, function(key,value) {
            $("#programa").append('<li data-role="list-divider">'+value.sala+'</li>').trigger('create');
            $.each(value.filmes, function(a,b) {
                $.each(b, function(c,d) {
                    $("#programa").append('<li>'+d+'</li>').trigger('create');
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

And even using .trigger("create") elements inserted in the page are not being styled by jQuery Mobile, I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you gotta use .listview("refresh") instead of .trigger

Comment: possible duplicate of [.listview() is not a function error when creating a dynamic listview in jquery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323981/listview-is-not-a-function-error-when-creating-a-dynamic-listview-in-jquery-m)

Comment: @James is working well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this -

```
$("#programa").listview("refresh");
```

/edit

I forgot to mention to try this listview refresh after your inner for each loop.

Comment: is working well! thank you!
But do not understand why this case .trigger() does not work.
When I use .trigger('create') to add buttons dynamically it usually stylized buttons.