# jQuery Mobile: $(...).listview is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to refresh a listview in jQuery Mobile after a dynamic insert of LI elements in an UL.
Whenever I try `$("#myUL").listview('refresh');`, on the console I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).listview is not a function

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.listview() is not a function error when creating a dynamic listview in jquery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323981/listview-is-not-a-function-error-when-creating-a-dynamic-listview-in-jquery-m)

Comment: Have you included jQuery mobile lib to your site/page ?

Comment: myUL is #ul1, so the code is: $(#ul1).listview('refresh');

I included:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

Comment: When are you calling listview("refresh")?

Comment: I'm using xmlhttp to execute an ajax call to a PHP file, and the output is thrown into my ul (#ul1). So the refresh is at the end of the function, after using xmlhttp.responseText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include jquery before jquery.mobile in head

```
... src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
... src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"
```

Check that the DOM is ready before doing refresh with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#playlist').listview('refresh');
});
```